# How to add a page adaptor to an ASP.NET project?

Tags: asp.net

I want to try the method of saving the viewstate to the DB as mentioned [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1293397.aspx/1?Store%20ViewState%20in%20the%20Database%20instead%20of%20Hidden%20Form%20Field/) but am confused by the PageAdaptor part. It says I should use app.browser to direct force my Adaptor to be used however, I don't use Visual Studio (using Delphi) so have no App_Browsers folder (if thats where it is) so I do not know how to tell my website that my custom adaptor should be used.

I have tried adding a .browser file to my website root but this doesn't help.

I appreciate I might be acting dumb here, just not sure :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an `App_Browsers` folder inside you ASP.Net Website, then inside this you can create a browsers file like the following `BrowserFile.browser` :

```
<!--
You can find existing browser definitions at
<windir>\Microsoft.NET\Framework\<ver>\CONFIG\Browsers
-->
<browsers>
  <browser refID="Default">
    <controlAdapters>
      <adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.UpdateProgress" adapterType="YourCompany.Web.UI.Adapters.UpdateProgressAdapter" />
    </controlAdapters>
    </browser>
</browsers>
```

Comment: I knew it must have been something simple. Thanks.